# Python & Selenium: How to get values generated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I use Selenium in Python for scraping.
I can't get values though these values are displayed on the browser.

So I checked the HTML source code, then I found that there are no values in HTML as below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="pos-list-body" class="list-body">

</div>
```

But there are values when I checked developer tool in chrome.

**DevTools**

```
<div id="pos-list-body" class="list-body">
    <div class="list-body-row" id="pos-row-1">
        <div class="pos-list-col-1">
            <input class="list-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1">
        </div>
        <div class="detail-data pos-list-col-2">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="detail-data pos-list-col-3">
            a
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="list-body-row" id="pos-row-2">
        <div class="pos-list-col-1">
            <input class="list-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2">
        </div>
        <div class="detail-data pos-list-col-2">
            2
        </div>
        <div class="detail-data pos-list-col-3">
            b
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

It seems that these values generated by JavaScript or something.

There is no `iframe` in sorce code.

How can I get these values with python?

It would be appreciated if you could give me some hint.

Comment: Do you mean that the elements show up after the page loads? Try putting a `time.sleep` to wait before trying to extract elements.

Comment: No, the elements in HTML are always blank after loading page. But the elements in DevTools exist. So result is the same if putting a `time.sleep`. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: What website is this from?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't show you the website because the page I ask needs login. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @SamuraiBlue which webdriver are you using with python selenium? If you're using a non-headless browser, have you tried inspecting the page in the same browser using the same credentials? Selenium should be able to get the injected HTML on the page, but there maybe something about your script implentation that's preventing the HTML from being injected into the #pos-list-body element. If you're not using a headless browser, it could be helpful to watch the script execution as you're running it, and see if you can gain additional insight from that.

Comment: You'd work with this just as you would any other page.  Selenium will access the DOM, which is what you are seeing in devTools.   If it's being tricky even when using webdriverwaits you may have a "lazy-loading" site, where the DOM has placeholders at first, then they are populated after page load or some other event.

Answer (score 1):

If ID `pos-list-body` is unique in `HTML-DOM`, then your best bet is to use `explicit wait` with `innerText`

**Code:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
print(wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "pos-list-body"))).get_attribute('innerText'))
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: The elements in HTML are always blank after loading page. But the elements in DevTools exist. So result is the same if putting `WebDriverWait` or `time.sleep`. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: you can extract it using `get_attribute('innerText')` that's the real answer in this answer

Comment: Nothing is printed when I tried your answer. When I tried `get_attribute('outerHTML')` instead of` `get_attribute('innerText')`, only div tag was printed as below. `<div id="pos-list-body" class="list-body">` and `</div>`.

Comment: Is it possible to share the link to the page?

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't share you the link to the page because the page needs login. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

### [Element.outerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)

The *`outerHTML`* attribute of the Element gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. It can also be set to replace the element with nodes parsed from the given string. However to only obtain the HTML representation of the contents of an element ideally you need to use the *`innerHTML`* property instead. So reading the value of *`outerHTML`* returns a DOMString containing an HTML serialization of the element and its descendants. Setting the value of outerHTML replaces the element and all of its descendants with a new DOM tree constructed by parsing the specified htmlString.

---

### Solution

To get the *html* generated by JavaScript you can use the following solution:

```
print(driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('pos-list-body').outerHTML"))
```

Comment: Only div tag was gotten as below, `<div id="pos-list-body" class="list-body">` and `</div>` though I tried your solution code. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Presumably you are looking for `1`, `a`, `2` and `b` at thr wrong place. That's not the desired node.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My question code is certainly editing to simplify my question because a lot of div tag and so on. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: First of all, this isn't a comment really but a well researched answer. However without further details about the real time scenario it would be unwise to speculate anything further.

Answer (score 0):

based on other answers that seems to be not working as a solution to your issue, one possibility left which is there are more then one HTML element in the DOM that has the ID : `pos-list-body`, and I guess the first retrieved element by this ID is really empty and it is not your targeted element.
Solution : try to select the `<div>` using Xpath instead of id, OR get all the elements with this id in a list and print the `innerHTML` of each one of them to get your targeted element index.

Comment: Although I tried your advice, it didn't work. `print(len(driver.find_elements(by=By.ID, value='pos-list-body')))` is 1. The result XPATH is `[]`. The result of `html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML") print(html)` doesn't exist any element I expect. Thank you for your answer. It would be appreciated if you could give me some hint.