# Python & Selenium: How to get Elements in DevTools with CDP (Chrome DevTools Protocol)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to get all source code in Elements with Chrome DevTools.

[image]

Although I tried the following code, these values are not match with the above code.

```
body = driver.execute_cdp_cmd("DOM.getOuterHTML", {"backendNodeId": 1})
print(body)
```

Is it possible to get all source code with CDP?
How can I get all source code with CDP?

I know the another way to scrape the source code.
But I'd like to know how to get the source code in Elements in DevTools. (F12)

Comment: Did you checked selenium official docs for python regarding this ?

Comment: I checked the following pages:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/ and https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/ . But I can't understand how to do. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: See CDP solution at the end**

Assuming by "f12 source code" you mean "the current DOM, after it has been manipulated by JS or anything else, as opposed to the original source code".

so, consider the following html page:

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hi</title> 
  <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+=" World!"
   }, 3000)
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="test">Hello</h1>
 
</body>
</html>
```

3 seconds after page load, the h1 will contain "Hello World!"

And that is exactly what we see when running the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://localhost:8000/") # replace with your page
sleep(6) # probably replace with smarter logic
html = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
print (html)
```

That outputs:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hi</title> 
  <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+=" World!"
   }, 3000)
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="test">Hello World!</h1>
 


</body></html>
```

***EDIT, using [CDP](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/) instead:***

The behavior you're describing is odd,  but okay, let's find a different solution.

It seems there's [limited](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/search?q=getdevtools) support for CDP in selenium 4 (so far) in python.
as of Now (May 2022) There is no driver.getDevTools() in python, only java and JS (Node) (?).

Anyway, I'm not even sure that would have helped us.

Raw CDP will suffice for now:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
# webdriver.remote.webdriver.import_cdp()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://localhost:8000/")
sleep(6)

doc = driver.execute_cdp_cmd(cmd="DOM.getDocument",cmd_args={})
doc_root_node_id = doc["root"]["nodeId"]
result = driver.execute_cdp_cmd(cmd="DOM.getOuterHTML",cmd_args={"nodeId":doc_root_node_id})
print (result['outerHTML'])
```

prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Hi</title> 
  <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML+=" World!"
   }, 3000)
});
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="test">Hello World!</h1>
 


</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work. As I'm asking another question in the following url, the elements in HTML are always blank after loading page. But the elements in DevTools exist. That's why I'm asking this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72022382/python-selenium-how-to-get-values-generated-by-javascript It would be appreciated if you could give me some hint.

Comment: Edited answer. Really weird that they only appear in dev tools. hopefully this time it works!

Comment: Thank you for update, but it doesn't work again. I can't get values. The result is still `<div id="pos-list-body" class="list-body">` and `</div>`

Comment: Please attach the output of ```driver.execute_cdp_cmd(cmd="DOM.getDocument",cmd_args={"depth": -1, "pierce": True})```, and also the source code of the page. i.e. hit Ctrl + U on the page and copy paste the result. *not from devtools*. ***Also, please run my code on other websites, see if it works there.***

Comment: Output is as below: `{'attributes': ['id', 'pos-list-body', 'class', 'list-body'], 'backendNodeId': 2639, 'childNodeCount': 0, 'children': [], 'localName': 'div', 'nodeId': 10068, 'nodeName': 'DIV', 'nodeType': 1, 'nodeValue': '', 'parentId': 10015}], 'localName': 'div', 'nodeId': 10015, 'nodeName': 'DIV', 'nodeType': 1, 'nodeValue': '', 'parentId': 9970}], 'localName': 'div', 'nodeId': 9970, 'nodeName': 'DIV', 'nodeType': 1, 'nodeValue': '', 'parentId': 9969}], 'localName': 'div', 'nodeId': 9969, 'nodeName': 'DIV', 'nodeType': 1, 'nodeValue': '', 'parentId': 9355},` There is no value expected